# Github Action -Author identity unknown error

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have this yaml for GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
name: Daily Standup CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "main"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 20
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '20'
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: 'maven'
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package -DskipTests --file pom.xml

  test:

    needs: build  # Runs when 'build' job is completed
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 20
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '20'
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: 'maven'
    - name: Run Tests
      run: mvn -B test --file pom.xml


  deploy:
    needs: test  # Runs when 'test' job is completed
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 20
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '20'
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: 'maven'
    - name: Read Current Snapshot Version
      id: read_snapshot_version
      run: echo ::set-output name=current_snapshot_version::$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=<version>)[^<]+" pom.xml | grep -E "SNAPSHOT")
    - name: Semantic Versioning for Snapshot
      id: update_snapshot_version
      run: |
        current_snapshot_version="${{ steps.read_snapshot_version.outputs.current_snapshot_version }}"
        IFS='.' read -r -a version_parts <<< "$current_snapshot_version"
        major="${version_parts[0]}"
        minor="${version_parts[1]}"
        patch="${version_parts[2]}"
        # When the last digit is 100
        if [[ "$patch" == "100" ]]; then
          minor=$((minor + 1))  # Increase minor version number
          patch="0"             # Reset last digit
        else
          patch=$((patch + 1))
        fi
        new_snapshot_version="${major}.${minor}.${patch}-SNAPSHOT"
        echo "::set-output name=new_snapshot_version::${new_snapshot_version}"
        sed -i "s/<version>.*-SNAPSHOT<\/version>/<version>${new_snapshot_version}<\/version>/" pom.xml
    - name: Commit and Push Semantic Snapshot Version
      run: |
        git commit -am "SNAPSHOT version to ${{ steps.update_snapshot_version.outputs.new_snapshot_version }}"
        git push origin HEAD:main
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}t
```

however it doesn't work for deploy stage. Error is this:

```
Run git commit -am "SNAPSHOT version to ..1-SNAPSHOT"

Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <runner@fv-az575-260.4axca1wo35oulg5iw0gfp2lodh.dx.internal.cloudapp.net>) not allowed
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

I don't understand this problem because I want to use the token with env however GitHub says where is  the username, name, git config.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the GITHUB_TOKEN isn't associated to any user, only to a bot. In that case, you may need to configure the username /email explicitly here (or use a PAT instead).

Comment: `git commit` knows nothing about tokens as tokens are for fetch/pull/push authentication, while `git commit` needs commit identification data, i.e. name+emaill, and it takes the data from config. You config is empty so you must add username+emaill before running `git commit`.

Comment: ` ` ` yaml
git config --global user.email "deployuser@dailystandup.com"
git config --global user.name "Deploy User"                                                        
`` ` i had added this line after your comment however unfourtnetly there is a error like this : fatal: unable to access 'url': The requested URL returned error: 403,Error: Process completed with exit code 128.

Comment: Error: 403 means authentication error. I.e., you successfully committed, now you need to debug your push.

Comment: You might need to set the permissions to allow `contents: write`

Comment: Thanks guys, i solved problem with your helps

Comment: @omerkarabas Is it possible you can post your solution as an accepted answer here? I have the same issue but setting permission `constents: write` does not fix the error code 128 issue